# How to share folder in local network using LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap

We have a folder that is shared by a windows application and a web application.
in the windows application we read all attachments files that have received by an speciall web mail. and then we store these on the shared folder.
In the web application we read shared folder's files and show them.

both applications are in local network.

my question is this:

How can I share this folder between these 2 applications?

The virsual server that windows application is running on, is : xxx.xxx.xx.110
The virsual server that Web application is running on, is xxx.xxx.xx.120

how these application can see a shared folder?

Is there any way for doing that by using LDAP? 
Thanks for any halping...

Comment: Where do you want your folder to reside? On the server machine or on the client machine?

Comment: On server machine. @CristinaAlboni

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 2 possible solutions:

1. `Give permissions to your folder to all AD users` or to the users the desktop application will run on

This is not difficult to implement, but there is a lack in security.

2. `Impersonate` the desktop application before the file copy operation, with a generic AD user and give this user rights on your folder. Don't forget to undo the impersonation once the action is done.

Below is a link to msdn explaining impersonation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376391(v=vs.85).aspx

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
impersonationContext = 
    ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

//Insert your code that runs under the security context of the authenticating user here.

impersonationContext.Undo();
```

Comment: I have used the first solution. I have gave permissions to this folder to all AD users, and in the client side, I map this folder as Y:\\ drive. so the problem is this: the valid path is server side is : C:\\sharedFolder and in client side is Y:\\sharedFolder. so I cant store in server and read in client. the path should be same (as applications implementation)

Comment: Use the path containing the machine name `\\serverName\sharedFolder`. This path works on the local computer and also on the network computers.

Comment: yes it worked. thanks. Can I share this folder by Active Directory Instead of manually?

Comment: I think the best way is to configure the shared folder permissions manually. I don't know how could you do this task automatically. I don't say it's not possible.